# Split numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Assuming there is a label vector y corresponding to training samples X

```
>>> y
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

If I use numpy.array_split directly it becomes

```
>>> np.array_split(y,2)
[array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 2, 2])]
```

How can I split y and X into 2 folders. So that y becomes

```
>>> y1
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> y2
    array([0, 1, 2])
```

PS: each label has the same number of samples. And I want to split them equivalently into folders. And each folder has only one sample per label.

Comment: `y[::2]` and `y[1::2]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "folders?"

Comment: If there are always two of each sample, just use `np.unique(y)`.  Otherwise you need to clarify just how you expect them to be split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is 5 times *less* efficient than the slicing solution. So, I add it here just for the sake of completeness.

```
a, b = y.reshape(y.shape[0]//2, 2).T
print(a)
#array([0, 1, 2])
print(b)
#array([0, 1, 2])
```